# Foreground for a single cell of automatic DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagridview, formatting

im trying to set the foreground of a single cell in a row of a DataGridView and i dont find a answer. The function load all DataGrid and change the foreground when find "Alta" but if i change the order of DataGrid (like ordering by Name) the foregrounds go to default again.
Here the function:

```
private void DataGrid_Color(DataGrid Grid)
        {
            Grid.UpdateLayout();
            foreach (DataRowView item in Grid.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (item.Row[7].Equals("Alta"))
                {
                    Grid.UpdateLayout();
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Grid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                       .ContainerFromItem(item);
                    DataGridCell column = Grid.Columns[7].GetCellContent(row)
                                                         .Parent as DataGridCell;
                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        column.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                    }
                }
                else if (item.Row[7].Equals("Média"))
                {
                    Grid.UpdateLayout();
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Grid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                       .ContainerFromItem(item);
                    DataGridCell column = Grid.Columns[7].GetCellContent(row)
                                                         .Parent as DataGridCell;
                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        column.Foreground = Brushes.Orange;
                    }
                }
                else if (item.Row[7].Equals("Baixa"))
                {
                    Grid.UpdateLayout();
                    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Grid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                   .ContainerFromItem(item);
                    DataGridCell column = Grid.Columns[7].GetCellContent(row)
                                                         .Parent as DataGridCell;
                    if (row != null)
                    {
                        column.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
                    }
                }
                Grid.UpdateLayout();
            }
        }
```

I try other function, whos load line per line but return null

```
        private void dgv_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ativo && coluna != -1)
            {
                DataRowView dataRowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
                if (Convert.ToString(dataRowView[coluna]).Equals("True"))
                {
                    e.Row.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
                    e.Row.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
                    e.Row.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 1, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have other way to change the single cell foreground in a DataGrid and dont return null or the foreground back to default?

Comment: When you call a datagrid a datagridview... somewhere there's a wpf fairy dies.  That's 2 you killed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the DataGridRow style for the column which you want to set the Foreground on different conditions, like below shown:

```
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Alta">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Média">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="Baixa">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: I tried change this condition in xaml but doesnt work, i think is because they DataGrid are automatic with UserControl.

Comment: Could you show the code for your DataGrid for me to analyze the issue and implement the function?